# Powershell copy directories and contents where name match with filter

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to copy some directories where name match with filter.
First of all I delete all the directories that match in the destination path, alfter I try to copy source directories and contents but I've a problem because are copied only files inside directories and subdirectories and not the directories names and structures.

```
$source="F:\origin"
$destination="F:\dest"
$filter="@"

# Remove dirs @ 
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -match $filter } | 
remove-item -Recurse

# Copy dirs and all contents
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -match $filter } | 
Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```

How can I do This ?
Thank you

EDIT

F:\origin\@test\index.php
F:\origin\@test1\index1.php
F:\origin\@test1\sub1\subindex1.php
F:\origin\no_consider\index1.php

Expected output
 
F:\dest\@test\index.php
F:\dest\@test1\index1.php
F:\dest\@test1\sub1\subindex1.php

Comment: could you add sample list of folders and the expected output?

Comment: It might be as simple as adding `Recurse` so it copies the contents of the directories? `Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Recurse`

Comment: @JamesC - -recurse not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a couple small tweaks seems to have done the trick. replaced some double quotes with single quotes, added a Recurse at the end of the one line and change DirectoryName to Name for the first one.
LEt me know if this works:

```
$source='c:\origin'
$destination='c:\dest'
$filter="@"

# Remove dirs @ 
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.Name -match $filter } | 
remove-item -Recurse


# Copy dirs and all contents
Get-ChildItem -Path $source | 
Where-Object { $_.Name -match $filter } | 
Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for! Thanks